# How To Parse Web API Controller Method Call in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Newbie here learning lots of MVC and Web API stuff.

I have a Web API (WebAPIController) defined (GET, GET/Id, PUT, POST, DELETE) and I want to consume the same in my MVC controller.

P.S. I've verified that the WebAPI calls works using POSTman (Chrome Extension).

My codes are as follows:

In my MVCController:

```
namespace MyApp.Controllers
{
  public class MVCController : Controller
  {
     private WebAPIController webAPICtrl = new WebAPIController();

     public ActionResult Index(int id)
     {
       var result = webAPICtrl.GetItem(id);

       // How to parse the result value here..
       // Need to validate some things on the result value.

     }
  }
}
```

The result variable is of type: `System.Web.Http.IHttpActionResult{System.Web.Http.Results.OkNegotiatedContentResult<TestItem>}`

In the Locals window of VS, I can see nested under the results variable is the Content containing the items defined for the TestItem class. These are the values which I need to get to do some sort of validation. So from the Locals window:

```
result
 > System.Web.Http.Results.OkNegotiatedContentResult<...>
    > Content
      > ItemID
      > ItemDescription
      > Price
```

I would need to get a hold of the values under the Content object.

I am unsure whether I am doing this the right way, and if someone could provide a more definitive method to obtain those values, that would be helpful.

Appreciate any input. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have good news for you.  MVC supports strong type models out of the box when an Action method is called.  This means that the Querysring is parsed for name/value pairs and a new istance of the class specified on the ActionMethod controler is automatically created and filled with values from the post.  Simply create a model in your project that has the properties you want to see, then add that a the parameter type in the action method like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyActionMethod(myType mt){
   if(ModelState.IsValid){
      var price = mt.Price;
      var itemid = mt.Itemid;
      // etc.....
   }
}
```

I often put a POST method in the model/viewmodel that does all of the behind the scenes work and changes the model for post back upon return with new values.  I don't do any parsing in the controller at all....

Answer (score 0):

```
var content = result.Content.ReadAsAsync<{datatype to read to}>().Result;
```

As a side Question do you mean to call your api controller directly from your mvc controller or do you mean to have it be an http call from your mvc controller?  because right now it is not an http call to the api controller

Comment: I'd like to call the API controller directly (for now), but if there's a better way in doing this, then I'd be more than happy to go that path.

Comment: it's just unusual and i wanted to make sure you knew you were doing it

Comment: I am quite stumped on the proper approach. Pretty much I just wanted to get the value returned by the web api.

Comment: Usually you would call the web api controller with an http call the same way you would call the original controller, in fact you might call the api controller directly instead of the mvc controller depending on what you were doing,  There are hundreds of different questions about this so you shouldn't have any trouble fining out how to do it.  The line of code above is how you read a response from an the default webapi response message